# Could not start the Mysql service on Local Computer "Error 3: The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to install "MYSQL -5.5.62-win32" on windows XP manually.

The existing MYSQL is MySQL 4.1.22-community-nt. It works like a breeze!

I have done the following:-

1. Stopped mysql server
2. my.ini

   - Renamed "my.ini" on c:/windows  =>"my_old.ini"
   - Copied "my-medium.ini" from "mysql-5.5.62-win32" folder to c:/windows
   - Renamed "my-medium.ini" => "my.ini" on c:/windows
3. mysql folder

   - Renamed "mysql" folder on c:/ =>"mysql_old"
   - Copied "mysql-5.5.62-win32" to c:/
   - Renamed "mysql-5.5.62-win32" =>"mysql"

Now, when I try to restart the mysql server, the following error message is displayed:

```
Could not start the Mysql service on Local Computer
Error 3: The system cannot find the path specified
```

Please note:-
Unlike the previous "my.ini" file, the new "my.ini" file  doesn't include any reference to the location of the "MYSQL" server.

This is the content of old "my.ini"

```ini
[mysqld]
basedir = C:/mysql/ 
datadir = C:/public_html/db/
[WinMySQLadmin]
Server=C:/mysql/bin/mysqld-nt.exe
user=[username]
password=password]
```

This is the content of the new "my.ini"

```ini
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
```

Please note that I couldn't find "mysql.sock" anywhere on the desktop.  I am told that there is no need for the line:-

`socket     = /tmp/mysql.sock`

MYSQL worked without it.

Please help!

Comment: With respect, if you are using an OS that was discontinued in 2009 and a MySQL version that was end of life in 2018, I'm not surprised you have trouble making it work. You will find few if any resources in supporting these versions. I suggest you upgrade to the current version of both OS and database.

Comment: Dear Bill, I'm trying to help someone in some 'difficult' country. Some people are less fortunate than others. If I can't help them, I shouldn't hurt them. Thanks for the advice, anyway!

Comment: Looks like "MYSQL -5.5.62-win32" is MYSQL NDB version. Having removed the MYSQL server and reinstalled it, these are the error messages:
- Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
- Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
- Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
- Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.

Any suggestion as to the right MYSQL version to download?

Comment: I looked into it, and MySQL 5.5 may be the most recent version that supports Windows XP. You do need to perform steps after installing to create new system tables. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/mysql-refman-5.5/programs.html#mysql-upgrade. This is getting far afield from a Stack Overflow answer. You really need a consultant.

Comment: Thank you, Bill, for the suggestion.  I will look into that and seek help elsewhere. If and when the issue is resolved, I will post a message here.  With best wishes  :)

Answer (score 0):

Bill's suggestion,"MySQL 5.5", would have been OK, but it needed a lot of work.

In the end, I tried "mysql-5.0.20-win32". It does the job and everyone is happy now.